Table Partition design Suggestion
I am looking for table partitioning design help to implement in UAT and then PROD.
The current process is from SP inserting data from staging table to main table and update table with business logic and delete data older than 90 days. The main table is 120 GB table with 100 Million data, the insert, update and delete takes more time about 1 hours to complete the process. Here I have posted -->ETL data load DML SP slowness suggestion
This process is running daily 4 times. I am trying to test and automate this process with table partitioning. The problem I have the data loads daily 4 times and sometimes we run extra batch as well based the requirement. I could not use daily or monthly partitioning, since I cannot switch in with data exists. I believe I need to use per load partitioning based on max current date. Can anyone assist.
We do not have any index other than primary key as clustered index.
Here is the test and sample I tested it out.
Table Creation:
--select top 10 * from [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW]

use master
go
alter database DB_Partition set single_user with rollback immediate
drop database DB_Partition
create database DB_Partition
go
use master
go

go
use DB_Partition
go
create schema [C1810429]

go
--*/
use DB_Partition
go

---1
--drop table [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW]
CREATE TABLE [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW](
    [STYTOTALID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [STYLE] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [InsertedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsCurrent] [bit] NULL,
    [DELDATTIM] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DELFLAG] [char](1) NULL,
    --/*
 CONSTRAINT [PK_C1810429_STYTOTAL_RAW] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [STYTOTALID] ASC,
    [STYLE] ASC,
    [InsertedDateTime] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)  
--*/
)

--*/


--drop table [C1810429].[DLSTYTOTAL]
CREATE TABLE [C1810429].[DLSTYTOTAL](
    [STYLE] [decimal](5, 0) NULL,   
    [DELDATTIM] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DELFLAG] [char](1) NULL
)

Insert Sample:
use DB_Partition

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME2(7) = '2024-05-01 00:00:00.000'

WHILE @DateTime <= '2024-10-18 23:59:59.999'
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW] ([STYLE],[InsertedDateTime])

 SELECT  ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%8)+1,@DateTime

 SET @DateTime = DATEADD(Minute, 1, @DateTime)
 

END
GO

Next Insert / batch Sample:
/*
use DB_Partition
-- populate further test data
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME2(7) = '20240701'
    
WHILE @DateTime <= '20241016'
BEGIN
    
     insert into [C1810429].[DLSTYTOTAL] ([STYLE])
    
     SELECT  ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%8)+1
    
     SET @DateTime = DATEADD(Minute, 1, @DateTime)
     
END
GO
*/
INSERT INTO  [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW] ([STYLE],[DELDATTIM],[DELFLAG],[InsertedDateTime],[IsCurrent])     

SELECT STG.[STYLE],STG.[DELDATTIM],STG.[DELFLAG],DATEADD(MICROSECOND, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), SYSDATETIME()) as [InsertedDateTime],1   as [IsCurrent]  
FROM [C1810429].[DLSTYTOTAL] STG Left Join [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW] TGT  
on STG.STYLE = TGT.STYLE AND STG.DELDATTIM = TGT.DELDATTIM
Where TGT.DELDATTIM is null

Update and Delete:
--update
UPDATE [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW]
SET ISCURRENT = 0,UpdatedDateTime = SYSDATETIME()                                      
WHERE IsCurrent = 1 

--delete
delete FROM [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW] 
WHERE InsertedDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, -90, SYSDATETIME()) and IsCurrent = 0 

Thanks for your help.
I have tested this monthly partition:
use DB_Partition
go
--drop PARTITION FUNCTION PF_myDateRange

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_myDateRange ( [datetime2](7))
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES 
(
'20240601',
'20240701',
'20240801',
'20240901',
'20241001',
'20241101'
)
GO
-- not sure I need to time as well in the function
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_myDateRange ( [datetime2](7))
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES 
(
'2024-06-01 23:59:59.997',
'2024-07-01 23:59:59.997',
'2024-08-01 23:59:59.997',
'2024-09-01 23:59:59.997',
'2024-10-01 23:59:59.997',
'2024-11-01 23:59:59.997'
)
GO
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_myPartitionScheme AS PARTITION PF_myDateRange ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);

-- drop and create index to make existing table into partition data alignment

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [PK_C1810429_STYTOTAL_RAW] ON [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW]
(
    [STYTOTALID] ASC,
    [STYLE] ASC,
    [InsertedDateTime] ASC
) 
WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
ON PS_myPartitionScheme([InsertedDateTime]);

Edited: I have tried to automate using max time and +1 seconds etc but the data while switching going to different partition boundary when I do load 2 and 3 etc.
---1
--drop table [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging]
CREATE TABLE [C1810429].STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging(
    [STYTOTALID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [STYLE] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [InsertedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsCurrent] [bit] NULL,
    [DELDATTIM] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DELFLAG] [char](1) NULL,
    --/*
 CONSTRAINT [PK_C1810429_STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [STYTOTALID] ASC,
    [STYLE] ASC,
    [InsertedDateTime] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)  

) on [Primary]--on PS_myPartitionScheme([InsertedDateTime]);

----

use DB_Partition
--truncate table C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
select * from C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
--00,06,12,18,23:59.59

-- load 1
select max([InsertedDateTime]) from [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW]
insert into C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 00:00:00.000')
insert into C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 01:00:00.000')
insert into C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 11:59:59.999')

-- load 2
select max([InsertedDateTime]) from [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW]
insert into C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 12:00:00.000')
insert into C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 13:00:00.000')
insert into C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 17:59:59.999')

-- load 3
select max([InsertedDateTime]) from [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW]
insert into C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 18:00:00.000')
insert into C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 19:00:00.000')
insert into C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 23:59:59.999')

--create new partitions for new data load use the primary FG
--get the staging table max date and add one minute and create new boundary
select max([InsertedDateTime]) from [C1810429].STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging

Declare @New_PartitionBoundaryDate_Plus datetime2 (7)
select @New_PartitionBoundaryDate_Plus = max (DATEADD(minute,+1,[InsertedDateTime])) from [C1810429].STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
select @New_PartitionBoundaryDate_Plus as [Plus]

--load 1  max([InsertedDateTime])
7   25920   2024-10-19 00:00:00.000
8   0   NULL

--load 2  max([InsertedDateTime])+ 1 minute

ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_myPartitionScheme     NEXT USED [Primary];
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_myDateRange ()  SPLIT RANGE('2024-10-19 11:59:59.9970000');
---------
--select *  from [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging]
select min([InsertedDateTime]) ,max([InsertedDateTime]) from [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging]
 
-- pass the min and max value of staging table
--load 1 >=  min([InsertedDateTime]) <=max([InsertedDateTime])
--load 2 >=  min([InsertedDateTime]) <=max([InsertedDateTime])

8   3   2024-10-19 12:00:59.997 -- Here the data is failling under
9   0   2024-10-19 18:00:59.997
10  0   NULL

ALTER TABLE [C1810429].STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Min_InsertedDateTime
CHECK ([InsertedDateTime] IS NOT NULL AND [InsertedDateTime] >= '2024-10-19 00:00:00.0000000' )

ALTER TABLE [C1810429].STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Max_InsertedDateTime
CHECK ([InsertedDateTime] IS NOT NULL AND [InsertedDateTime] <= '2024-10-19 11:59:59.9970000' )

-- get the data for bounday and enter the partition no or date

-- Create partition for each load by getting max datetime of [InsertedDateTime] in table  [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW]
--2024-10-19 12:00:00.001
Declare @New_PartitionBoundaryDate_SWITCH datetime2 (7)
select @New_PartitionBoundaryDate_SWITCH = max (DATEADD(minute,0,[InsertedDateTime]))  from [C1810429].STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
select @New_PartitionBoundaryDate_SWITCH as [SWITCH] --Get the swith parttion

--load 1 is not working since the last data is in that boundary value
ALTER TABLE   [C1810429].STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging SWITCH TO [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW] PARTITION $PARTITION.PF_myDateRange('2024-10-19 11:59:59.997');

--load 1 taken last not null boundary partition no
--load 1 taken last not null boundary partition no
ALTER TABLE [C1810429].STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging SWITCH TO [C1810429].[STYTOTAL_RAW] PARTITION 8 -- 2024-10-19 12:00:00.001

declare @ck_Min_InsertedDateTime_drop varchar (max)
set @ck_Min_InsertedDateTime_drop = 'ALTER TABLE [C1810429].STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
drop CONSTRAINT ck_Min_InsertedDateTime;'
--select @ck_Min_InsertedDateTime_drop
Exec (@ck_Min_InsertedDateTime_drop)

declare @ck_Max_InsertedDateTime_drop varchar (max)
set @ck_Max_InsertedDateTime_drop = 'ALTER TABLE [C1810429].STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
drop CONSTRAINT ck_Max_InsertedDateTime;'
--select @@ck_Max_InsertedDateTime_drop
Exec (@ck_Max_InsertedDateTime_drop)



To clarify better - I have a multiple data load or insert per day that will auto generate date from -DATEADD(MICROSECOND, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), SYSDATETIME()) as [InsertedDateTime] in the staging load.

I am getting this error so I added 1 minute.
ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed. Check constraints or partition function of source table
'DB_Partition.C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging' allows values that are not allowed by check constraints or partition function on target table
'DB_Partition.C1810429.STYTOTAL_RAW'.

There are few points might cause your fail:

You created the partition function with last partition point '2024-11-01.xxx', if you forgot remove it before alter function in load 1, you will split partition ['2024-10-01.xxx', '2024-11-01.xxx') to 2 parts, which are ['2024-10-01.xxx', '2024-10-19.xxx') and ['2024-10-19.xxx', '2024-11-01.xxx'). Thus may cause your CHECK for right bound unmatch.
In real, you always append dataset on the end of target table, and the last partition has opened right bound, so you need not limit max value by CHECK in the table which will be switched.
As I said in comment, you declared RIGHT in partition function, the value of split point would be included in its right partition, in your case of load 1, '2024-10-19 00:00:00.000' should be included in new partition, so the min CHECK must be >='2024-10-19 00:00:00.000'.

I rearranged your code:

Create target table and staging table that same as your code.
Fill target table and make partitions on target table which same as your code.
Remove last partition '2024-11-01.xxx' from target partitions.
Fill data in staging table like you.
Get min(InsertedDateTime) from staging table as new split point.
Create a new partition with the split point from step 5.
Add/modify the CHECK of left bound in staging table which is greate than or equals(>=) the split point from step 5.
Switch the staging table.

Here is the code, test it
--Create target table, copy from your script except dbname
CREATE TABLE [STYTOTAL_RAW](
    [STYTOTALID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [STYLE] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [InsertedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsCurrent] [bit] NULL,
    [DELDATTIM] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DELFLAG] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_C1810429_STYTOTAL_RAW] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [STYTOTALID] ASC,
    [STYLE] ASC,
    [InsertedDateTime] ASC
)
)
GO

--Create function, copy from your script
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_myDateRange ( [datetime2](7))
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES 
(
'2024-06-01 23:59:59.997',
'2024-07-01 23:59:59.997',
'2024-08-01 23:59:59.997',
'2024-09-01 23:59:59.997',
'2024-10-01 23:59:59.997',
'2024-11-01 23:59:59.997'
)
GO

--Create SCHEME, copy from your script
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_myPartitionScheme AS PARTITION PF_myDateRange ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);

-- drop and create index to make existing table into partition data alignment
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [PK_C1810429_STYTOTAL_RAW] ON [STYTOTAL_RAW]
(
    [STYTOTALID] ASC,
    [STYLE] ASC,
    [InsertedDateTime] ASC
) 
WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
ON PS_myPartitionScheme([InsertedDateTime]);
GO

--fill data, copy from your script
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME2(7) = '2024-05-01 00:00:00.000'
WHILE @DateTime <= '2024-10-18 23:59:59.999'
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO [STYTOTAL_RAW] ([STYLE],[InsertedDateTime])
  SELECT  ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%8)+1,@DateTime
 SET @DateTime = DATEADD(Minute, 1, @DateTime)
END
GO

--Create staging table copy from your script
CREATE TABLE STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging(
    [STYTOTALID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [STYLE] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [InsertedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsCurrent] [bit] NULL,
    [DELDATTIM] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DELFLAG] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_C1810429_STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [STYTOTALID] ASC,
    [STYLE] ASC,
    [InsertedDateTime] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)  

) on [Primary]

-- remove last partition you created before, to make the last partition not be limited(open right bound)
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_myDateRange ()  MERGE RANGE('2024-11-01 23:59:59.997');

DECLARE @split_point [datetime2](7)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

--load 1
--prepare data
insert into STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 00:00:00.000')
insert into STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 01:00:00.000')
insert into STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 11:59:59.999')

--Get min date as new partition's split point(left bound)
SELECT @split_point = MIN(InsertedDateTime) FROM STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging

--code from youe script
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_myPartitionScheme     NEXT USED [Primary];
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_myDateRange ()  SPLIT RANGE(@split_point);

--drop CHECK if exists
ALTER TABLE STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS ck_Min_InsertedDateTime

--Create left bound CHECK only, because this table will move to the last partition of target table, it's right bound is open, until next spliting. 
SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Min_InsertedDateTime
    CHECK ([InsertedDateTime] IS NOT NULL AND [InsertedDateTime] >= ''' + FORMAT(@split_point, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff') + ''')'

EXECUTE( @sql )

--switching
ALTER TABLE STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging SWITCH TO [STYTOTAL_RAW] PARTITION $PARTITION.PF_myDateRange(@split_point);

--load 2, repeat the process
insert into STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 12:00:00.000')
insert into STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 13:00:00.000')
insert into STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging (STYLE,InsertedDateTime) values (1,'2024-10-19 17:59:59.999')

SELECT @split_point = MIN(InsertedDateTime) FROM STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging

ALTER PARTITION SCHEME PS_myPartitionScheme     NEXT USED [Primary];
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PF_myDateRange ()  SPLIT RANGE(@split_point);

ALTER TABLE STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS ck_Min_InsertedDateTime

SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Min_InsertedDateTime
    CHECK ([InsertedDateTime] IS NOT NULL AND [InsertedDateTime] >= ''' + FORMAT(@split_point, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff') + ''')'

EXECUTE( @sql )

ALTER TABLE STYTOTAL_RAW_Intermediate_Staging SWITCH TO [STYTOTAL_RAW] PARTITION $PARTITION.PF_myDateRange(@split_point);

